# Get all span text with jquery?

Tags: jquery, each

```
<div id="product">
<span class="tag">lorem ipsum<span class="remove"></span></span>
<span class="tag">lorem ipsum<span class="remove"></span></span>
<input type="hidden" id="selected-value" value="">
</div>
```

İ want get all span text and paste to hidden input with jQuery.
Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected-value" value="lorem ipsum,lorem ipsum">
```

Post data : `'lorem ipsum,lorem ipsum'`

I did try this code but not working:

```
$( "#product span" ).each(function( index ) {
      $('#selected-value').val("," + $( this ).text());
});
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the answer. Instead mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it.  (You are welcome to post an answer to your own question, if you feel you have a solution better than those offered by others; but post it as an answer, not as part of the question.)

Answer (score 1):

You said you need ALL span text, well, here it is, although maybe you meant only `span.tag` and leave out the emptiness of `span.remove`, in that case just add `.tag` to the selector

```js
var texts = [];
$( "#product span" ).each(function( index ) {
if($(this).text().match(/ +/, false))
      texts.push($( this ).text());
});
$('#selected-value').val(texts.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
<span class="tag">lorem ipsum1<span class="remove"></span></span>
<span class="tag">lorem ipsum2<span class="remove"></span></span>
<input type="hidden" id="selected-value" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, because why not:

```js
var output = $('span')
  .toArray()              // so we can use filter and map
  .map(function(e) {      // get the text contents instead of the whole node
    return $(e).text()
  })
  .filter(Boolean)        // drop empty elements from the array
  .join(", ");            // Join into a comma-separated string

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
  <span class="tag">lorem ipsum<span class="remove"></span></span>
  <span class="tag">lorem ipsum<span class="remove"></span></span>
  <input type="hidden" id="selected-value" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change te #product span to $(".tag")

Like this:

```
$( ".tag" ).each(function( index, value ) {
      var oldInputs = $("#selected-value").val();
      $('#selected-value').val(oldInputs +"," $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: i did but getting last span text :/

Comment: var arr = ''; $( ".tag" ).each(function( index ) {
   arr += $( this ).text() + ',';
 });

Answer (score 0):

First loop through all the spans and extract what you want. Finally use that result as you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var textvalues = [];
  $( "#product>span" ).each(function() {
      textvalues.push($( this ).text())
  });

  $('#selected-value').val(textvalues.join(","));
});
```